# Jenkins: How to disable report file date check

Tags: jenkins, xunit

I'm having trouble running tests on Jenkins. I get this error

```
[xUnit] [ERROR] - Test reports were found but not all of them are new. Did all the tests run?
  * /path/to/report.xml is 3.1 sec old
```

I read that Jenkins is checking the report file date to be sure not take reports from previous build. I'm not sure I need this so I want to disable this check.

I read [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17520) and [there](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS/issues/JENKINS-6268?filter=allopenissues) that this should be possible but can't find how.

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: I think Reports were not generated when you run the job, check whether reports were generated or not. Also check the path generated manually.

Comment: I checked the file is here and it's not empty.